# Mongoid query by reference attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

here is a simple structure:

```
class Dinner
  belongs_to :user
  field :name

class User
  has_many :dinners
  field :name
```

now, what i want is to find all the dinners hosted by 'John'. looking for something like:

```
Dinner.where('user.name' => 'john')
```

the problem is that i cannot find any way to query by referenced attribute. any suggestions?

Comment: Dinner.includes(:user).where(:name => 'john')
Is this not working?

Comment: @SachinR, no because Dinner also can have the `name` attrubute

Comment: Dinner.includes(:user).where("user.name = ? ", 'john')

Comment: @SachinR you confuse it with active record stuff. you can't do it on mongoid.

Comment: Can you provide all the conditions you require for the query?

Answer (score 3):

I think it just won't work with your model.
AFAIK querying by nested attributes works only for embedded documents.
You have two options:

```
Dinner.where(user: User.find_by(name: 'john'))
```

Or store user name directly in Dinner. It's redundant, but makes your query simplier.

MongoDB is not relational database and doesn't support joins.